# Matching a string in curly quotation marks

Tags: python, regex

Hi im trying to use regex in python 2.7 to search for text inbetween two quotation marks such as "hello there". Right now im using:

```
matchquotes = re.findall(r'"(?:\\"|.)*?"', text)
```

It works great but only finds quotes using this character: **"**

However I'm finding sometimes that some text that im parsing use these DIFFERENT characters: **“** ... **”**

How can I modify my regex such that it will find either **"**..**"** or **“**.. **”** or **"**..**”**

Answer (score 2):

Using character classes might work, or might break everything for you:

```
matchquotes = re.findall(r'[“”"](?:\\[“”"]|.)*?[“”"]', text)
```

If you don't care a lot about matching pairs always lining up, this will probably do what you want. The case where they use the third type inside the other two is always going to screw you unless you build a few patterns and find their intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what other processing you are doing and where the text is coming from, it would be better to convert all quotation marks to " rather than handle each case.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but for those type of 'fancy' quotes, I would first get their codes which are like **\xe2\x80\x9c** or **\u2019** from a table. Then I would try to match them writing their regex codes. For that purpose this might be helpful: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html

I hope it helps!